# How to list subnets in a network using golang?

Tags: go, subnet

I want to list no. of subnets in a network, I have sample working code in python but require it in golang.

```
NETWORK="192.168.0.0/16"
subnet_prefix=22
net = ipaddress.ip_network(NETWORK)
for subnet in net.subnets(new_prefix=subnet_prefix):
    net = ipaddress.ip_interface(subnet)
    print(net)
```

`192.168.0.0/22 192.168.4.0/22 192.168.8.0/22 192.168.12.0/22 192.168.16.0/22 192.168.20.0/22 192.168.24.0/22 192.168.28.0/22 192.168.32.0/22 192.168.36.0/22 192.168.40.0/22 192.168.44.0/22 192.168.48.0/22 192.168.52.0/22 192.168.56.0/22 192.168.60.0/22 192.168.64.0/22 192.168.68.0/22 192.168.72.0/22 192.168.76.0/22 192.168.80.0/22 192.168.84.0/22 192.168.88.0/22 192.168.92.0/22 192.168.96.0/22 192.168.100.0/22 192.168.104.0/22 192.168.108.0/22 192.168.112.0/22 192.168.116.0/22 192.168.120.0/22 192.168.124.0/22 192.168.128.0/22 192.168.132.0/22 192.168.136.0/22 192.168.140.0/22 192.168.144.0/22 192.168.148.0/22 192.168.152.0/22 192.168.156.0/22 192.168.160.0/22 192.168.164.0/22 192.168.168.0/22 192.168.172.0/22 192.168.176.0/22 192.168.180.0/22 192.168.184.0/22 192.168.188.0/22 192.168.192.0/22 192.168.196.0/22 192.168.200.0/22 192.168.204.0/22 192.168.208.0/22 192.168.212.0/22 192.168.216.0/22 192.168.220.0/22 192.168.224.0/22 192.168.228.0/22 192.168.232.0/22 192.168.236.0/22 192.168.240.0/22 192.168.244.0/22 192.168.248.0/22 192.168.252.0/22`

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems have you encountered? Be specific.

Comment: A /16 can be divided into 2^(22-16)=64 /22 subnets. The first 16 bits are constant, the last 32-22=10 bits (32 for IPv4) determine the host addresses in each subnet, so you have 6 bits to play with. Data types for dealing with this are in the [net/netip package](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function I wrote generates all the subnets of given `subnetMaskSize` that can be created inside a given `netCIDR`. Network and subnets are in all in CIDR notation.

E.g.:

```golang
func Runner() {
    fmt.Println(GenSubnetsInNetwork("192.168.0.0/24", 26))
}
```

```bash
=== RUN   TestRunner/run_me
[192.168.0.0/26 192.168.0.64/26 192.168.0.128/26 192.168.0.192/26] <nil>
--- PASS: TestRunner (0.00s)
```

I chose arithmetic operations hence it's easier to understand(for better performance use bitwise operations).

The function calculates some facts about the given network and subnetMask, then it generates all the subnet CIDRs.

```golang
func GenSubnetsInNetwork(netCIDR string, subnetMaskSize int) ([]string, error) {
    ip, ipNet, err := net.ParseCIDR(netCIDR)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if !ip.Equal(ipNet.IP) {
        return nil, errors.New("netCIDR is not a valid network address")
    }
    netMaskSize, _ := ipNet.Mask.Size()
    if netMaskSize > int(subnetMaskSize) {
        return nil, errors.New("subnetMaskSize must be greater or equal than netMaskSize")
    }

    totalSubnetsInNetwork := math.Pow(2, float64(subnetMaskSize)-float64(netMaskSize))
    totalHostsInSubnet := math.Pow(2, 32-float64(subnetMaskSize))
    subnetIntAddresses := make([]uint32, int(totalSubnetsInNetwork))
    // first subnet address is same as the network address
    subnetIntAddresses[0] = ip2int(ip.To4())
    for i := 1; i < int(totalSubnetsInNetwork); i++ {
        subnetIntAddresses[i] = subnetIntAddresses[i-1] + uint32(totalHostsInSubnet)
    }

    subnetCIDRs := make([]string, 0)
    for _, sia := range subnetIntAddresses {
        subnetCIDRs = append(
            subnetCIDRs,
            int2ip(sia).String()+"/"+strconv.Itoa(int(subnetMaskSize)),
        )
    }
    return subnetCIDRs, nil
}

func ip2int(ip net.IP) uint32 {
    if len(ip) == 16 {
        panic("cannot convert IPv6 into uint32")
    }
    return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(ip)
}
func int2ip(nn uint32) net.IP {
    ip := make(net.IP, 4)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(ip, nn)
    return ip
}
```

Comment: You're awesome @Neo Anderson

Comment: How do I make this work with ipv6?

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think the arithmetic approach in my answer is appropriate for IPv6, because IPv6 is represented on 128 bits, and you may have already realised that `int2ip` and `ip2int` won't work as they are now. Those may eventually be refactored to use `math/big` instead of uint32, but then you still have to find a replacement for `binary.BigEndian.PutUint32` and also get rid of the assumption that an IP address is represented on 32 bits from`GenSubnetsInNetwork`. There are several go libraries that could help as a starting point e.g.: https://github.com/c-robinson/iplib

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution using a different library. Though the one you link to looks better.

Comment: @Jonathan, yep, this answer is just a human friendly example done with integer values. The same core principle applied here would still be valid for IPv6, but you need a small full fledged library with helpers that can do addition and subtraction directly in binary. Speaking about that library, I think [this unit test](https://github.com/c-robinson/iplib/blob/85813efada10e35dfe279f4f91531b02a778f7a6/net6_test.go#L491)  highlights the functionality you are looking for, pretty much out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer works well for ipv4 but I needed a function that can handle both ipv4 and ipv6. Here is what I came up with;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"

    netaddr "github.com/dspinhirne/netaddr-go"
)

func breakIntoSubnets(network string, newCidr uint) ([]string, error) {
    ip, _, err := net.ParseCIDR(network)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    if ip.To4() != nil {
        newCidr = 21
        parsedNetwork, err := netaddr.ParseIPv4Net(network)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error parsing network (%s) with netaddrr", network)
            return nil, err
        }
        subnets := make([]string, 0)
        for i := 0; i <= int(parsedNetwork.SubnetCount(newCidr)); i++ {
            subnet := parsedNetwork.NthSubnet(newCidr, uint32(i))
            if subnet == nil {
                return subnets, nil
            }
            subnets = append(subnets, subnet.String())
        }

        return subnets, nil
    } else {
        newCidr = 40
        parsedNetwork, err := netaddr.ParseIPv6Net(network)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error parsing network (%s) with netaddrr", network)
            return nil, err
        }
        subnets := make([]string, 0)
        for i := 0; i <= int(parsedNetwork.SubnetCount(newCidr)); i++ {
            subnet := parsedNetwork.NthSubnet(newCidr, uint64(i))
            if subnet == nil {
                return subnets, nil
            }
            subnets = append(subnets, subnet.String())
        }

        return subnets, nil
    }

}

func main() {
    subnets, err := breakIntoSubnets("2601:9000::/20", 48)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
    }

    for _, subnet := range subnets {
        fmt.Println(subnet)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a few lines of code with the [ipaddress-go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/), and doesn't require maintaining separate code for IPv4 vs IPv6. Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the library.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    listSubnets("192.168.0.0/16", 22)
    listSubnets("2001:db8::1a20/124", 126)
}

func listSubnets(original string, newPrefix int) {
    subnet := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(original).GetAddress()
    iterator := subnet.SetPrefixLen(newPrefix).PrefixIterator()
    for iterator.HasNext() {
        fmt.Print(iterator.Next(), " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

`192.168.0.0/22 192.168.4.0/22 192.168.8.0/22 192.168.12.0/22 192.168.16.0/22 192.168.20.0/22 192.168.24.0/22 192.168.28.0/22 192.168.32.0/22 192.168.36.0/22 192.168.40.0/22 192.168.44.0/22 192.168.48.0/22 192.168.52.0/22 192.168.56.0/22 192.168.60.0/22 192.168.64.0/22 192.168.68.0/22 192.168.72.0/22 192.168.76.0/22 192.168.80.0/22 192.168.84.0/22 192.168.88.0/22 192.168.92.0/22 192.168.96.0/22 192.168.100.0/22 192.168.104.0/22 192.168.108.0/22 192.168.112.0/22 192.168.116.0/22 192.168.120.0/22 192.168.124.0/22 192.168.128.0/22 192.168.132.0/22 192.168.136.0/22 192.168.140.0/22 192.168.144.0/22 192.168.148.0/22 192.168.152.0/22 192.168.156.0/22 192.168.160.0/22 192.168.164.0/22 192.168.168.0/22 192.168.172.0/22 192.168.176.0/22 192.168.180.0/22 192.168.184.0/22 192.168.188.0/22 192.168.192.0/22 192.168.196.0/22 192.168.200.0/22 192.168.204.0/22 192.168.208.0/22 192.168.212.0/22 192.168.216.0/22 192.168.220.0/22 192.168.224.0/22 192.168.228.0/22 192.168.232.0/22 192.168.236.0/22 192.168.240.0/22 192.168.244.0/22 192.168.248.0/22 192.168.252.0/22`

`2001:db8::1a20/126 2001:db8::1a24/126 2001:db8::1a28/126 2001:db8::1a2c/126`